# How to calculate $e^{i+1}$?

Tags: calculus

How do I calculate $e^{i+1}$?

I know that $e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0$, but I don't see how this is related if there is no $\pi$ in the question and the $+1$ just confuses me.

Comment: See [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula). In your case, $\alpha=1$.

Comment: First off, remember $x^ax^b = x^{a + b}$ so $e^{i + 1} = e^ie^1$ or just $ee^i$.  Second $e^{\theta i} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$, for you $\theta = 1$, so it's just $e^i = \cos(1) + i\sin(1)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can separate the expression according to the real and imaginary parts of the exponent:

$$e^{i+1}=e^i\cdot e^1$$

Of those two, $e^i$ is a point located exactly $1$ radian around the unit circle from $1$ (in the counterclockwise direction). That part's related to the $e^{\pi i}$ equation, which works because $-1$ is $\pi$ radians from $1$ around the circle.

The other factor, $e^1$, is just the real number $e$. Therefore, you've got a complex number $e$ units from the origin in the direction $1$ radian from the real axis. Its real and imaginary parts are $e\cos 1$ and $e\sin 1$.

Answer (score 6):

$$e^{i+1} = e^1\cdot e^{i\cdot 1} = e(\cos 1 + i\sin 1).$$

Answer (score 3):

Use Euler's formula, $e^{ix}=\cos{x}+i\sin{x}$

$e^{i+1}=e\times e^i=e\left(\cos{1}+i\sin{1}\right)$